# Can I split a single reStructuredText file into multiple HTML pages by section?

Tags: restructuredtext

I have a long reStructuredText file that I render into HTML. I'd like to spit each section into a different HTML page, for greater readability. Is it possible, without splitting the source file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. From http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/markup/toctree.html

> reST does not have facilities to…split documents into multiple output files.